# Problem with output from this FOR command

Tags: windows, command-line

I just realized I'm executing a bat file at the start at this registry key, that had `echo running abc` and some other irrelevant things

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

So here I've modified that bat file.. it is just one line nothing irrelevant in it.

you see the contents of the bat file.

Here is some output from the cmd prompt showing the situation now which is the same fundamental problem but you should be able to reproduce the problem

The question now is,

- Why does it say echo sss and not echo sss ttt?
- How can I suppress the running of cmd or that initialization bat file with the FOR? The FOR statement should really just display "echo g", not "echo sss" or "echo sss ttt".

---

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
sss ttt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>cd\

C:\>type \blah\startfile.bat <ENTER>
@echo sss ttt   

C:\>  

C:\>for /f %f in ('echo g ^| findstr "g"') do echo %f <ENTER>

C:\>echo sss
sss

C:\>echo g
g

C:\>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. What version of windows is that?

Comment: I got "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: It works as expected for me (Win 7) - no mystery "echo running" command.

Comment: @techie007 xp but just tried it on another machine and it's only on one computer

Comment: @jaquer  ^ is the escape character try it without it and you see it needs it. otherwise it might try doing the | early in processing and gives an error as you see if you don't use ^.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it say echo sss and not echo sss ttt?

Because the line `sss ttt` contains a space character. The `for` command tokenize it and stores first half `sss` in `%f` and second half `ttt` in `%g` variable.

> How can I suppress the running of cmd or that initialization bat file
>   with the FOR? The FOR statement should really just display "echo g",
>   not "echo sss" or "echo sss ttt".

Seems like in order to evaluate `echo g ^| findstr "g"` a new command interpreter is initialized and your `\blah\startfile.bat` is automatically executed. Make your batch not to output anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `%f` in a batch file, you need to escape it with another `%`:

```
for /f %%f in ('echo g ^| findstr "g"') do echo %%f
```

Put that in your batch file and you should get the results you're looking for.

Comment: The FOR was not in a batch file. Try reading the question more carefully. Look at the dump from the command prompt.

Comment: Whoops.  Yep, I see that now.  I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a bit on Vlastimil's answer...

When the **`FOR`** command executes the **`"echo g"`** and pipes the output to **`findstr`**, **FOR** has to first start a new command processor which causes **`\blah\startfile.bat`** to be executed.

**\blah\startfile.bat** outputs a line containing **`sss ttt`**. That line is processed by **FOR** and is **NOT** passed to **findstr**.

According the the help for **FOR**:

> **Processing consists of ..., breaking it up into
>   individual lines of text and then parsing each line into zero or more tokens.  The body of the for loop is then called with the variable value(s) set to the found token string(s). By default, /F
>   passes the first blank separated token from each line...**

The default delimiters for **FOR** are: **" ,;"** (space comma and semi-colon).

The first line that **FOR** processes contains the string: **sss ttt**. That string contains a **`" "`** (space), which is a default delimiter for **FOR**, which parses the line and assigns the first token string: **"sss"** to **"%f"**. So the **"echo %f"** outputs a line with only: **"sss"**. That is the first line you see printed. The **"ttt"** is simply discarded because the **"FOR ... echo %f"** command did not specify to include anything more than the first token.

If the **FOR** command was written differently, you would have seen the full line **"sss ttt"** echoed.

Here are 3 ways the **FOR** command could have been written to do that.

The first way, using the **`"delims="`** option, sets the delimiter for **FOR** to "empty", so **FOR** returns the entire line as 1 token. The tokens are still parsed, and all delimiters (**" ,;"**) are removed, then all the tokens are combined again with a space between each token. This combined value is returned in the variable **"%f"**

```
C:\>for /f "delims=" %f in ('echo sss ttt')  do echo %f

C:\>echo sss ttt
sss ttt

C:\>for /f "delims=" %f in ('echo mm;nn,oo, ;ss ,, tt') do echo %f

C:\>echo mm nn oo ss tt
mm nn oo ss tt
```

This next way, using the **`"tokens=*"`** option, tells **FOR** to put all of the tokens found into the value of the specified variable (**"%f"**). The tokens are still parsed, and all delimiters are removed, then all the tokens are combined again with a space between each token.

```
C:\>for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('echo sss ttt')  do echo %f

C:\>echo sss ttt
sss ttt

C:\>for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('echo mm;nn,oo, ;ss ,, tt') do echo %f

C:\Users\1-kevin>echo mm nn oo ss tt
mm nn oo ss tt
```

This third way, using the **`"tokens=1,*"`** option, tells **FOR** to put the first (1) token found into the value of the specified variable (**"%f"**). And, the remaining tokens are parsed, and all delimiters are removed, then all those remaining tokens are combined again with a space between each token, and this combined value is returned in the variable named with the letter that follows the specified variable name (so in this case, variable **"%g"**).

```
C:\>for /f "tokens=1,*" %f in ('echo sss ttt')  do echo %f %g

C:\>echo sss ttt
sss ttt

C:\>for /f "tokens=1,*" %f in ('echo mm;nn,oo, ;ss ,, tt') do echo "%f" "%g"

C:\>echo "mm" "nn oo ss tt"
"mm" "nn oo ss tt"
```

Note that the following will not work because there are no "tokens=" defined for variables beyond the specified variable of **"%f"**:

```
C:\>for /f %f in ('echo sss ttt')  do echo %f %g

C:\>echo sss %g
sss %g
```

So, in your example, if you added the **`"delims="`** option, you would see this:

```
C:\>for /f "delims=" %f in ('echo g ^| findstr "g"') do echo %f

C:\>echo sss ttt
sss ttt

C:\>echo g
g

C:\>
```